# How to create shape triangle shape on bottom of image using css

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I would like to add triangle shape on bottom of my image just like on image below.

[image]

Comment: Am voting to reopen this question because the 'duplicate' question's answers just place any old triangle on the image whereas this question's image shows the 'triangle' is actually an integral part of the image. The question could be better phrased - author if you see this explore clip-path and if you get stuck put your code in the question to see if it can be reopened and we can help.

Comment: @AHaworth updated the duplicate